# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, FLOAT datatype issue, Oracle 11gR2

Tags: sql, oracle, floating-point-precision, sqldatatypes

I have been trying to store the price of the products. So I need 2 decimal points and datatype should be float, i think.

I am using Oracle 11gR2. Following is what I have written.

```
create table test (
product varchar2(20),
price   float(5,2));
```

It should be working, but it is giving me an error : 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

If I put NUMBER instead of float, or if I write float(5), still it works.
but if i write float(5,2), it causes error. I believe I am right, but I am confused.

Can anybody please give me a brief explanation of what is happening or what wrong I have done.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref129), you can only specify a precision for `float`,  not a scale.

Quote from the manual:

> *Scale cannot be specified*

So it should be `FLOAT(2)`

But I hope you are aware of all the downsides of the `FLOAT` data type. It is an *approximate* type. You don't necessarily get back what you put in.

For more details please see this: http://floating-point-gui.de

Using `float` is almost always the wrong choice.

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, I have checked the link (manual) you provided. So I am going to use NUMBER datatype now. Thank you for providing me the most reliable information.

Comment: @Murshed: no offence, but you could have consulted the manual yourself before asking here.

Comment: Base-2^n floating point types prove the existence of (your favorite deity here) by negation, because they are clearly the work of (your favorite personification of evil here). :-)